# npm ERR! premature close when using npm install

Tags: github, npm, npm-install

Getting [..................] / rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 5d754927a47910d2 on installing from github.

Tried multiple things like cleaning cache, resetting proxy, etc but none of them work.

> sudo npm install --save github:saarthak-jain/Blockchainbois-Voting

The log file attached is

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'saarthak-jain/Blockchainbois-Voting'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.2.0
4 verbose npm-session 5d754927a47910d2
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for github:saarthak-jain/Blockchainbois-Voting premature close
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 7432ms
10 verbose stack Error: premature close
10 verbose stack     at PassThrough.onclose (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/end-of-stream/index.js:47:67)
10 verbose stack     at PassThrough.emit (events.js:201:15)
10 verbose stack     at emitCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:8)
10 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
11 verbose cwd /home/saarthak/FrontEnd
12 verbose Linux 4.18.0-18-generic
13 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "saarthak-jain/Blockchainbois-Voting"
14 verbose node v12.2.0
15 verbose npm  v6.9.0
16 error premature close
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Please post the package.json text

Answer (score 11):

In my case, the package I was trying to install had a dependency on a Git repository that didn't have a package.json defined yet.  My solution was to checkin/push the missing package.json.

Comment: thanks, had the exact same issue! the npm error logs are not helpful at all there...

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to "answer" this in case anyone gets here for the same reason I did.

```
npm install some/package
```

will fail with:

```
npm ERR! premature close
```

if "some/package" does not actually exist. Check to **make sure you have the correct spelling** on your package name.

For your entertainment, I was supposed to be using:

```
composer require some/package
```

Answer (score 3):

After running `yarn install` I got this error:

```
error Error parsing JSON at "git://github.com/<xxx>.git/package.json", "Unexpected token } in JSON at position <yyy>".
```

Turns out I broke the `package.json` in `<xxx>`, fixing that solved the issue.

So:

1. run `yarn install`, it may have a better log.
2. `package.json` bugs can cause this.

Comment: "run yarn install, it may have a better log." THANK YOU. You saved me lots of time. Why `npm` does not give a proper error message? It is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation when trying to install a package from Github with an invalid `package.json` file.

The file had an extra comma (,) and because of this I was faced with the same `Error: premature close` error.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, in my case the issue was a malformed semver version specified inside the package.json of the module that I was trying to install.

Make sure that the target module has a valid semver version in the `version` field of the `package.json`

Comment: didn't helped me

Comment: Exactly my issue. In my depencies' package.json, I had manually put version as "1". In fact it must be version "1.0.0" according to semver documentation: https://github.com/npm/node-semver

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and in my case I eventually discovered that the issue was that my `/tmp` folder was read-only. This only seemed to affect github dependencies, presumably because git checks out those repos in `/tmp`. Other dependencies would install fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same and it was caused by the package built with the latest NPM version, and then the attempt to download it with an older one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error (a lot of them, one for each dependency i think) when using `yarn install` maybe this is a similar issue with `npm`

```
➤ YN0013: │ @aws-sdk/middleware-user-agent@npm:3.226.0 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0001: │ Error [ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE]: Premature close
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at PassThrough.onclose (node:internal/streams/end-of-stream:154:30)
    at PassThrough.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at emitCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:132:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
```

And what helped is to upgrade the yarn version, in my case it was `3.0.2 -> 3.6.4`
And this solved everything. Hope it helps someone.