# how to use npm package from private github?

Tags: node.js, github

I create a new npm package example test in project exist example server. And i add this package test in dependancy at server.

```
 "package_name":"git+https://x-oauth-basic:<github_token>@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git"
```

when i run `npm install` the console displays an error `premature close`.

```
npm ERR! premature close
    
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 

npm ERR!     xxxxxxx\xxxxx\2021-06-09T14_25_10_140Z-debug.log
```

2021-06-09T14_25_10_140Z-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.0.0
4 verbose npm-session 0409e58ecfce8f4a
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 2438ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 16ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 419ms
16 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
17 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for package_name@git+https://x-oauth-basic:<github_token>@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git premature close
18 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
19 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 20557ms
20 silly saveTree +-- @firebase/rules-unit-testing@1.2.7
20 silly saveTree | +-- @firebase/component@0.4.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @firebase/util@0.4.1
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- tslib@2.2.0
20 silly saveTree | | `-- tslib@2.2.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- @firebase/logger@0.2.6
20 silly saveTree | +-- @firebase/util@0.4.1
20 silly saveTree | +-- firebase@8.3.3
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @firebase/analytics@0.6.8
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- @firebase/analytics-types@0.4.0
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- @firebase/installations@0.4.24
20 silly saveTree | | |   +-- @firebase/installations-types@0.3.4
20 silly saveTree | | |   `-- idb@3.0.2
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @firebase/app-types@0.6.2
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @firebase/app@0.6.19
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- dom-storage@2.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- xmlhttprequest@1.8.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @firebase/auth@0.16.4
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- @firebase/auth-types@0.10.2
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @firebase/database@0.9.8
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- @firebase/auth-interop-types@0.1.5
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- @firebase/database-types@0.7.1
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- faye-websocket@0.11.3
20 silly saveTree | | |   `-- websocket-driver@0.7.4
20 silly saveTree | | |     +-- http-parser-js@0.5.3
20 silly saveTree | | |     +-- safe-buffer@5.1.2
20 silly saveTree | | |     `-- websocket-extensions@0.1.4
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @firebase/firestore@2.2.3
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- @firebase/firestore-types@2.2.0
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- @firebase/webchannel-wrapper@0.4.1
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- @grpc/grpc-js@1.2.12
20 silly saveTree | | | | +-- @types/node@14.0.23
20 silly saveTree | | | | +-- google-auth-library@6.1.6
20 silly saveTree | | | | | +-- arrify@2.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | +-- base64-js@1.3.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | +-- ecdsa-sig-formatter@1.0.11
20 silly saveTree | | | | | +-- fast-text-encoding@1.0.3
20 silly saveTree | | | | | +-- gaxios@4.2.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | +-- abort-controller@3.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | | `-- event-target-shim@5.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | +-- extend@3.0.2
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | +-- https-proxy-agent@5.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | | +-- agent-base@6.0.2
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | | | `-- debug@4.3.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | | |   `-- ms@2.1.2
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | | `-- debug@4.3.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | +-- is-stream@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | `-- node-fetch@2.6.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | +-- gcp-metadata@4.2.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | `-- json-bigint@1.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | | |   `-- bignumber.js@9.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | +-- gtoken@5.2.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | +-- google-p12-pem@3.0.3
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | | `-- node-forge@0.10.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | `-- jws@4.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | | |   `-- jwa@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | | |     `-- buffer-equal-constant-time@1.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | +-- jws@4.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | | `-- lru-cache@6.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | |   `-- yallist@4.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | `-- semver@6.3.0
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- @grpc/proto-loader@0.5.6
20 silly saveTree | | | | +-- lodash.camelcase@4.3.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | `-- protobufjs@6.10.2
20 silly saveTree | | | |   +-- @protobufjs/aspromise@1.1.2
20 silly saveTree | | | |   +-- @protobufjs/base64@1.1.2
20 silly saveTree | | | |   +-- @protobufjs/codegen@2.0.4
20 silly saveTree | | | |   +-- @protobufjs/eventemitter@1.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | | |   +-- @protobufjs/fetch@1.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | | |   | `-- @protobufjs/inquire@1.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | | |   +-- @protobufjs/float@1.0.2
20 silly saveTree | | | |   +-- @protobufjs/inquire@1.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | | |   +-- @protobufjs/path@1.1.2
20 silly saveTree | | | |   +-- @protobufjs/pool@1.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | | |   +-- @protobufjs/utf8@1.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | | |   +-- @types/long@4.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | | |   +-- @types/node@13.13.48
20 silly saveTree | | | |   `-- long@4.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- node-fetch@2.6.1
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @firebase/functions@0.6.6
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- @firebase/functions-types@0.4.0
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- @firebase/messaging-types@0.5.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @firebase/installations@0.4.24
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @firebase/messaging@0.7.8
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @firebase/performance@0.4.10
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- @firebase/performance-types@0.0.13
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @firebase/polyfill@0.3.36
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- core-js@3.6.5
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- promise-polyfill@8.1.3
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- whatwg-fetch@2.0.4
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @firebase/remote-config@0.1.35
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- @firebase/remote-config-types@0.1.9
20 silly saveTree | | `-- @firebase/storage@0.4.7
20 silly saveTree | |   `-- @firebase/storage-types@0.3.13
20 silly saveTree | `-- request@2.88.2
20 silly saveTree |   +-- aws-sign2@0.7.0
20 silly saveTree |   +-- aws4@1.10.0
20 silly saveTree |   +-- caseless@0.12.0
20 silly saveTree |   +-- combined-stream@1.0.8
20 silly saveTree |   | `-- delayed-stream@1.0.0
20 silly saveTree |   +-- forever-agent@0.6.1
20 silly saveTree |   +-- form-data@2.3.3
20 silly saveTree |   | +-- asynckit@0.4.0
20 silly saveTree |   | `-- mime-types@2.1.27
20 silly saveTree |   |   `-- mime-db@1.44.0
20 silly saveTree |   +-- har-validator@5.1.3
20 silly saveTree |   | +-- ajv@6.12.3
20 silly saveTree |   | | +-- fast-deep-equal@3.1.3
20 silly saveTree |   | | +-- fast-json-stable-stringify@2.1.0
20 silly saveTree |   | | +-- json-schema-traverse@0.4.1
20 silly saveTree |   | | `-- uri-js@4.2.2
20 silly saveTree |   | |   `-- punycode@2.1.1
20 silly saveTree |   | `-- har-schema@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree |   +-- http-signature@1.2.0
20 silly saveTree |   | +-- assert-plus@1.0.0
20 silly saveTree |   | +-- jsprim@1.4.1
20 silly saveTree |   | | +-- extsprintf@1.3.0
20 silly saveTree |   | | +-- json-schema@0.2.3
20 silly saveTree |   | | `-- verror@1.10.0
20 silly saveTree |   | |   `-- core-util-is@1.0.2
20 silly saveTree |   | `-- sshpk@1.16.1
20 silly saveTree |   |   +-- asn1@0.2.4
20 silly saveTree |   |   | `-- safer-buffer@2.1.2
20 silly saveTree |   |   +-- bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.2
20 silly saveTree |   |   | `-- tweetnacl@0.14.5
20 silly saveTree |   |   +-- dashdash@1.14.1
20 silly saveTree |   |   +-- ecc-jsbn@0.1.2
20 silly saveTree |   |   | `-- jsbn@0.1.1
20 silly saveTree |   |   +-- getpass@0.1.7
20 silly saveTree |   |   +-- jsbn@0.1.1
20 silly saveTree |   |   +-- safer-buffer@2.1.2
20 silly saveTree |   |   `-- tweetnacl@0.14.5
20 silly saveTree |   +-- is-typedarray@1.0.0
20 silly saveTree |   +-- isstream@0.1.2
20 silly saveTree |   +-- json-stringify-safe@5.0.1
20 silly saveTree |   +-- mime-types@2.1.27
20 silly saveTree |   +-- oauth-sign@0.9.0
20 silly saveTree |   +-- performance-now@2.1.0
20 silly saveTree |   +-- qs@6.5.2
20 silly saveTree |   +-- tough-cookie@2.5.0
20 silly saveTree |   | `-- psl@1.8.0
20 silly saveTree |   +-- tunnel-agent@0.6.0
20 silly saveTree |   `-- uuid@3.4.0
20 silly saveTree +-- @googlemaps/google-maps-services-js@3.1.16
20 silly saveTree | +-- agentkeepalive@4.1.4
20 silly saveTree | | +-- depd@1.1.2
20 silly saveTree | | `-- humanize-ms@1.2.1
20 silly saveTree | |   `-- ms@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- axios@0.21.1
20 silly saveTree | | `-- follow-redirects@1.13.3
20 silly saveTree | +-- query-string@6.14.1
20 silly saveTree | | +-- decode-uri-component@0.2.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- filter-obj@1.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- split-on-first@1.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | `-- strict-uri-encode@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | `-- retry-axios@2.4.0
20 silly saveTree +-- @sendgrid/mail@7.2.1
20 silly saveTree | +-- @sendgrid/client@7.4.2
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @sendgrid/helpers@7.4.2
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- deepmerge@4.2.2
20 silly saveTree | | `-- axios@0.21.1
20 silly saveTree | `-- @sendgrid/helpers@7.2.0
20 silly saveTree |   `-- chalk@2.4.2
20 silly saveTree |     +-- ansi-styles@3.2.1
20 silly saveTree |     | `-- color-convert@1.9.3
20 silly saveTree |     |   `-- color-name@1.1.3
20 silly saveTree |     +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
20 silly saveTree |     `-- supports-color@5.5.0
20 silly saveTree |       `-- has-flag@3.0.0
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/big.js@4.0.5
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/chai-subset@1.3.3
20 silly saveTree | `-- @types/chai@4.2.11
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/chai@4.2.11
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/cookie-parser@1.4.2
20 silly saveTree | `-- @types/express@4.17.7
20 silly saveTree |   +-- @types/body-parser@1.19.0
20 silly saveTree |   | `-- @types/connect@3.4.33
20 silly saveTree |   +-- @types/express-serve-static-core@4.17.8
20 silly saveTree |   | +-- @types/qs@6.9.3
20 silly saveTree |   | `-- @types/range-parser@1.2.3
20 silly saveTree |   +-- @types/qs@6.9.3
20 silly saveTree |   `-- @types/serve-static@1.13.4
20 silly saveTree |     `-- @types/mime@2.0.2
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/cors@2.8.6
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/debug@4.1.5
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/deep-equal-in-any-order@1.0.1
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/express@4.17.7
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/graphviz@0.0.32
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/http-errors@1.8.0
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/mocha@8.0.0
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/mock-fs@4.10.0
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/moment-duration-format@2.2.2
20 silly saveTree | `-- moment@2.27.0
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/morgan@1.9.1
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/mustache@4.0.1
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/mysql@2.15.15
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/node-fetch@2.5.7
20 silly saveTree | `-- form-data@3.0.0
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/node@14.0.23
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/qs@6.9.3
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/request@2.48.5
20 silly saveTree | +-- @types/caseless@0.12.2
20 silly saveTree | +-- @types/tough-cookie@4.0.0
20 silly saveTree | `-- form-data@2.5.1
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/sinon-chai@3.2.4
20 silly saveTree | `-- @types/sinon@9.0.4
20 silly saveTree |   `-- @types/sinonjs__fake-timers@6.0.1
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/sinon@9.0.4
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/supertest@2.0.10
20 silly saveTree | `-- @types/superagent@4.1.8
20 silly saveTree |   `-- @types/cookiejar@2.1.1
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/uuid@8.0.0
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/validator@13.1.0
20 silly saveTree +-- @types/ws@7.2.6
20 silly saveTree +-- @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint@4.26.1
20 silly saveTree | +-- @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@4.26.1
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @types/json-schema@7.0.7
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @typescript-eslint/scope-manager@4.26.1
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- @typescript-eslint/types@4.26.1
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- @typescript-eslint/visitor-keys@4.26.1
20 silly saveTree | | |   `-- eslint-visitor-keys@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @typescript-eslint/types@4.26.1
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@4.26.1
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- globby@11.0.3
20 silly saveTree | | | | +-- array-union@2.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | +-- dir-glob@3.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | `-- path-type@4.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | +-- fast-glob@3.2.5
20 silly saveTree | | | | | +-- @nodelib/fs.stat@2.0.4
20 silly saveTree | | | | | +-- @nodelib/fs.walk@1.2.6
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | +-- @nodelib/fs.scandir@2.1.4
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | | `-- run-parallel@1.2.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | |   `-- queue-microtask@1.2.3
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | `-- fastq@1.11.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | | |   `-- reusify@1.0.4
20 silly saveTree | | | | | +-- glob-parent@5.1.2
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | `-- is-glob@4.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | |   `-- is-extglob@2.1.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | +-- merge2@1.4.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | +-- micromatch@4.0.2
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | +-- braces@3.0.2
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | | `-- fill-range@7.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | |   `-- to-regex-range@5.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | |     `-- is-number@7.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | | | `-- picomatch@2.2.2
20 silly saveTree | | | | | `-- picomatch@2.2.2
20 silly saveTree | | | | +-- ignore@5.1.8
20 silly saveTree | | | | +-- merge2@1.4.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | `-- slash@3.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- is-glob@4.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- semver@7.3.5
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- tsutils@3.21.0
20 silly saveTree | | |   `-- tslib@1.14.1
20 silly saveTree | | +-- eslint-scope@5.1.1
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- esrecurse@4.3.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | `-- estraverse@5.2.0
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- estraverse@4.3.0
20 silly saveTree | | `-- eslint-utils@3.0.0
20 silly saveTree | `-- lodash@4.17.21
20 silly saveTree +-- @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@4.22.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@4.22.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @types/json-schema@7.0.5
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @typescript-eslint/scope-manager@4.22.0
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- @typescript-eslint/types@4.22.0
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- @typescript-eslint/visitor-keys@4.22.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @typescript-eslint/types@4.22.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@4.22.0
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- semver@7.3.5
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- tsutils@3.21.0
20 silly saveTree | | |   `-- tslib@1.14.1
20 silly saveTree | | +-- eslint-scope@5.1.1
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- esrecurse@4.3.0
20 silly saveTree | | |   `-- estraverse@5.2.0
20 silly saveTree | | `-- eslint-utils@2.1.0
20 silly saveTree | |   `-- eslint-visitor-keys@1.3.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- @typescript-eslint/scope-manager@4.22.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- functional-red-black-tree@1.0.1
20 silly saveTree | +-- regexpp@3.1.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- semver@7.3.5
20 silly saveTree | `-- tsutils@3.21.0
20 silly saveTree |   `-- tslib@1.14.1
20 silly saveTree +-- @typescript-eslint/parser@4.22.0
20 silly saveTree +-- axios@0.21.1
20 silly saveTree +-- big.js@5.2.2
20 silly saveTree +-- chai-subset@1.6.0
20 silly saveTree +-- chai@4.3.4
20 silly saveTree | +-- assertion-error@1.1.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- check-error@1.0.2
20 silly saveTree | +-- deep-eql@3.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | `-- type-detect@4.0.8
20 silly saveTree | +-- get-func-name@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- pathval@1.1.1
20 silly saveTree | `-- type-detect@4.0.8
20 silly saveTree +-- class-transformer@0.2.3
20 silly saveTree +-- class-validator@0.12.2
20 silly saveTree | +-- @types/validator@13.0.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- google-libphonenumber@3.2.10
20 silly saveTree | +-- tslib@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | `-- validator@13.0.0
20 silly saveTree +-- commander@6.0.0
20 silly saveTree +-- cookie-parser@1.4.5
20 silly saveTree | +-- cookie-signature@1.0.6
20 silly saveTree | `-- cookie@0.4.0
20 silly saveTree +-- cors@2.8.5
20 silly saveTree | +-- object-assign@4.1.1
20 silly saveTree | `-- vary@1.1.2
20 silly saveTree +-- cross-env@7.0.2
20 silly saveTree | `-- cross-spawn@7.0.3
20 silly saveTree |   +-- path-key@3.1.1
20 silly saveTree |   +-- shebang-command@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree |   | `-- shebang-regex@3.0.0
20 silly saveTree |   `-- which@2.0.2
20 silly saveTree |     `-- isexe@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree +-- debug@4.3.1
20 silly saveTree +-- deep-equal-in-any-order@1.1.4
20 silly saveTree | +-- lodash.mapvalues@4.6.0
20 silly saveTree | `-- sort-any@1.2.3
20 silly saveTree |   `-- lodash@4.17.21
20 silly saveTree +-- dotenv@8.2.0
20 silly saveTree +-- eslint-plugin-import@2.22.1
20 silly saveTree | +-- array-includes@3.1.3
20 silly saveTree | | +-- call-bind@1.0.2
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- function-bind@1.1.1
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- get-intrinsic@1.1.1
20 silly saveTree | | |   +-- has-symbols@1.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | |   `-- has@1.0.3
20 silly saveTree | | +-- define-properties@1.1.3
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- object-keys@1.1.1
20 silly saveTree | | +-- es-abstract@1.18.0
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- es-to-primitive@1.2.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | +-- is-callable@1.2.0
20 silly saveTree | | | | +-- is-date-object@1.0.2
20 silly saveTree | | | | `-- is-symbol@1.0.3
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- has-symbols@1.0.2
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- is-callable@1.2.3
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- is-negative-zero@2.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- is-regex@1.1.2
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- is-string@1.0.5
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- object-inspect@1.9.0
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- object.assign@4.1.2
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- string.prototype.trimend@1.0.4
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- string.prototype.trimstart@1.0.4
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- unbox-primitive@1.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | |   +-- has-bigints@1.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | |   +-- has-symbols@1.0.2
20 silly saveTree | | |   `-- which-boxed-primitive@1.0.2
20 silly saveTree | | |     +-- is-bigint@1.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | |     +-- is-boolean-object@1.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | |     `-- is-number-object@1.0.4
20 silly saveTree | | +-- get-intrinsic@1.1.1
20 silly saveTree | | `-- is-string@1.0.5
20 silly saveTree | +-- array.prototype.flat@1.2.4
20 silly saveTree | | `-- es-abstract@1.18.0
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- has-symbols@1.0.2
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- is-callable@1.2.3
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- is-regex@1.1.2
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- object-inspect@1.9.0
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- object.assign@4.1.2
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- string.prototype.trimend@1.0.4
20 silly saveTree | |   `-- string.prototype.trimstart@1.0.4
20 silly saveTree | +-- contains-path@0.1.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- debug@2.6.9
20 silly saveTree | +-- doctrine@1.5.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- esutils@2.0.3
20 silly saveTree | | `-- isarray@1.0.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- eslint-import-resolver-node@0.3.4
20 silly saveTree | | +-- debug@2.6.9
20 silly saveTree | | `-- resolve@1.17.0
20 silly saveTree | |   `-- path-parse@1.0.6
20 silly saveTree | +-- eslint-module-utils@2.6.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- debug@2.6.9
20 silly saveTree | | `-- pkg-dir@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | |   `-- find-up@2.1.0
20 silly saveTree | |     `-- locate-path@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | |       +-- p-locate@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | |       | `-- p-limit@1.3.0
20 silly saveTree | |       |   `-- p-try@1.0.0
20 silly saveTree | |       `-- path-exists@3.0.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- has@1.0.3
20 silly saveTree | +-- minimatch@3.0.4
20 silly saveTree | | `-- brace-expansion@1.1.11
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- balanced-match@1.0.0
20 silly saveTree | |   `-- concat-map@0.0.1
20 silly saveTree | +-- object.values@1.1.3
20 silly saveTree | | `-- es-abstract@1.18.0
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- has-symbols@1.0.2
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- is-callable@1.2.3
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- is-regex@1.1.2
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- object-inspect@1.9.0
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- object.assign@4.1.2
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- string.prototype.trimend@1.0.4
20 silly saveTree | |   `-- string.prototype.trimstart@1.0.4
20 silly saveTree | +-- read-pkg-up@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- find-up@2.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- locate-path@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | |   +-- p-locate@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | |   | `-- p-limit@1.3.0
20 silly saveTree | | |   |   `-- p-try@1.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | |   `-- path-exists@3.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | `-- read-pkg@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- load-json-file@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | |   | +-- graceful-fs@4.2.4
20 silly saveTree | |   | +-- parse-json@2.2.0
20 silly saveTree | |   | | `-- error-ex@1.3.2
20 silly saveTree | |   | |   `-- is-arrayish@0.2.1
20 silly saveTree | |   | +-- pify@2.3.0
20 silly saveTree | |   | `-- strip-bom@3.0.0
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- normalize-package-data@2.5.0
20 silly saveTree | |   | +-- hosted-git-info@2.8.9
20 silly saveTree | |   | +-- semver@5.7.1
20 silly saveTree | |   | `-- validate-npm-package-license@3.0.4
20 silly saveTree | |   |   +-- spdx-correct@3.1.1
20 silly saveTree | |   |   | +-- spdx-expression-parse@3.0.1
20 silly saveTree | |   |   | | +-- spdx-exceptions@2.3.0
20 silly saveTree | |   |   | | `-- spdx-license-ids@3.0.7
20 silly saveTree | |   |   | `-- spdx-license-ids@3.0.7
20 silly saveTree | |   |   `-- spdx-expression-parse@3.0.1
20 silly saveTree | |   `-- path-type@2.0.0
20 silly saveTree | |     `-- pify@2.3.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- resolve@1.17.0
20 silly saveTree | `-- tsconfig-paths@3.9.0
20 silly saveTree |   +-- @types/json5@0.0.29
20 silly saveTree |   +-- json5@1.0.1
20 silly saveTree |   | `-- minimist@1.2.5
20 silly saveTree |   +-- minimist@1.2.5
20 silly saveTree |   `-- strip-bom@3.0.0
20 silly saveTree +-- eslint@7.24.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/code-frame@7.12.11
20 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/highlight@7.10.4
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- @babel/helper-validator-identifier@7.10.4
20 silly saveTree | |   `-- js-tokens@4.0.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- @eslint/eslintrc@0.4.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- ajv@6.12.6
20 silly saveTree | | +-- espree@7.3.1
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- acorn-jsx@5.3.1
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- acorn@7.4.1
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- eslint-visitor-keys@1.3.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- globals@12.4.0
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- type-fest@0.8.1
20 silly saveTree | | +-- ignore@4.0.6
20 silly saveTree | | +-- import-fresh@3.3.0
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- parent-module@1.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | | | `-- callsites@3.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- resolve-from@4.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- js-yaml@3.13.1
20 silly saveTree | | | +-- argparse@1.0.10
20 silly saveTree | | | | `-- sprintf-js@1.0.3
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- esprima@4.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | `-- strip-json-comments@3.1.1
20 silly saveTree | +-- chalk@4.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- ansi-styles@4.3.0
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- color-convert@2.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | |   `-- color-name@1.1.4
20 silly saveTree | | `-- supports-color@7.1.0
20 silly saveTree | |   `-- has-flag@4.0.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- doctrine@3.0.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- enquirer@2.3.6
20 silly saveTree | | `-- ansi-colors@4.1.1
20 silly saveTree | +-- eslint-scope@5.1.1
20 silly saveTree | | `-- esrecurse@4.3.0
20 silly saveTree | |   `-- estraverse@5.2.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- espree@7.3.1
20 silly saveTree | +-- esquery@1.4.0
20 silly saveTree | | `-- estraverse@5.2.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- file-entry-cache@6.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | `-- flat-cache@3.0.4
20 silly saveTree | |   +-- flatted@3.1.1
20 silly saveTree | |   `-- rimraf@3.0.2
20 silly saveTree | |     `-- glob@7.1.4
20 silly saveTree | |       +-- fs.realpath@1.0.0
20 silly saveTree | |       +-- inflight@1.0.6
20 silly saveTree | |       | +-- once@1.4.0
20 silly saveTree | |       | | `-- wrappy@1.0.2
20 silly saveTree | |       | `-- wrappy@1.0.2
20 silly saveTree | |       +-- inherits@2.0.3
20 silly saveTree | |       +-- once@1.4.0
20 silly saveTree | |       `-- path-is-absolute@1.0.1
20 silly saveTree | +-- globals@13.8.0
20 silly saveTree | | `-- type-fest@0.20.2
20 silly saveTree | +-- ignore@4.0.6
20 silly saveTree | +-- import-fresh@3.3.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- imurmurhash@0.1.4
20 silly saveTree | +-- js-yaml@3.13.1
20 silly saveTree | +-- json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify@1.0.1
20 silly saveTree | +-- levn@0.4.1
20 silly saveTree | | +-- prelude-ls@1.2.1
20 silly saveTree | | `-- type-check@0.4.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- lodash@4.17.21
20 silly saveTree | +-- natural-compare@1.4.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- optionator@0.9.1
20 silly saveTree | | +-- deep-is@0.1.3
20 silly saveTree | | +-- fast-levenshtein@2.0.6
20 silly saveTree | | `-- word-wrap@1.2.3
20 silly saveTree | +-- progress@2.0.3
20 silly saveTree | +-- semver@7.3.5
20 silly saveTree | +-- strip-ansi@6.0.0
20 silly saveTree | | `-- ansi-regex@5.0.0
20 silly saveTree | +-- strip-json-comments@3.1.1
20 silly saveTree | +-- table@6.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- ajv@8.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- mime@2.5.2
20 silly saveTree | | +-- onetime@5.1.2
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- mimic-fn@2.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- p-limit@3.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | | `-- yocto-queue@0.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- pumpify@2.0.1
20 silly saveTree | | +-- snakeize@0.1.0
20 silly saveTree | | +-- stream-events@1.0.5
20 silly saveTree | | `-- xdg-basedir@4.0.0
20 silly saveTree | |   |   | `-- p-limit@2.3.0
20 silly saveTree | |   |   `-- path-exists@3.0.0
20 silly saveTree | `-- webpack-sources@2.3.0
20 silly saveTree |   +-- source-list-map@2.0.1
20 silly saveTree |   `-- source-map@0.6.1
20 silly saveTree `-- ws@7.4.6
21 verbose stack Error: premature close
21 verbose stack     at PassThrough.onclose (C:\Users\Andromalala\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:47:67)
21 verbose stack     at PassThrough.emit (events.js:201:15)
21 verbose stack     at emitCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:8)
21 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:17)
22 verbose cwd 
23 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
24 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
25 verbose node v12.0.0
26 verbose npm  v6.9.0
27 error premature close
28 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: What's in the log?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118038/npm-err-premature-close-when-using-npm-install) help?

Comment: Is the `package.json` in the other repository correct? https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20824 seems to imply that may be the issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton I update this question